# Syntax for swing timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I would like my button to flash red and its default color

```
public class Jbutton {
    public static void main (String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    JButton button = new JButton("I'm colorful!");
    frame.add(button);
    button.setBackground(color.Red);
    (timer here for 1 sec.);
    button.setBackground(color.originalColor);
    }
}
```

What is the timer syntax? And can you tell it to wait a certain amount of time?  Milliseconds, seconds, minutes, etc.?  Which one?

And How do you get the original color of the button back?  You know; the color if you only do

`JButton button = new JButton("Button");
frame.add(button);`

Comment: The Timer syntax is well explained in the tutorial -- have you looked at this first? It's easy to find, just Google `java swing timer tutorial` and I'm betting it's the first hit. Regarding setting original color back, you could try `setBackground(null)` on the button and see what that does. -1 for not showing your effort though. Please fix this, show us your attempt from what you gleaned from the tutorials so I can remove my -1 vote.

Comment: Edit: yep, I just tried it and it is in fact the first Google hit for `java swing timer tutorial`. Please give it a look.

Comment: As was previously recommended to you, try [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Oh and a [runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820488/java-swing-jbutton-time-delays-flicker/23820554#23820554)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Import

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
```

Syntax

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //...Perform a task...
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
timer.start(); //start the timer
```